# Using jQuery to pull data from google sheets

Tags: jquery, excel, google-sheets

I am using jQuery to pull data from google sheets and then rendering that into an HTML output. The process is working great, however, I am now trying to get the data from an individual row based on a value in the row. I am guessing that in my "for each" I should be passing a value... however I'm stumped. Here is what I assume to be the chunk of code I need to modify:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
var entry = data.feed.entry;
$(entry).each(function(){
```

Based on this value: `this.gsx$propertyid.$t;`

Any clues or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are asking? This might work if it is what you are asking for.

```
var spreadsheetID = "somevalue";
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/1/public/values?alt=json";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {                  
    var entry = data.feed.entry;              
    $(entry).each(function(){
      alert(this.gsx$propertyid.$t); //or whatever action of using the value
    });                 
});
```

```js
var spreadsheetID = "1xkfPWIYFdZpE9v9JMlmWSObxIHIjOKQdjB7qb4Nrdps";
var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/" + spreadsheetID + "/1/public/values?alt=json";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var entry = data.feed.entry;

  $(entry).each(function() {
    alert(this.gsx$title.$t);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I actually have that bit working. The each statement returns all the values I need. To give a bit more insight I want to grab a specific row (based on the propertyid) from the sheet that is equal to the propertyid I have and then inject that into a modal (which I also have working)... but at this point I am only ever getting that last row in the sheet.   I'm guessing this would be something like:     $(propertyid).each(function()?

Comment: This might be more of a JSON jQuery question. Something like: $(entry).each(function(){ where data is equal to propertyID?